# Importing new records and updating employee-manager data

Tags: sql-update, hierarchy

I have spent a day researching and trying various samples without success in being able to update imported records from a lookup table, however most samples use a straightforward lookup table that has the relevant info, which is not the scenario I have.

I am importing employee records into a Users table. I have created an Import table that contains the employee details as well as the manager Email address for each user. For example: FirstName, LastName, Email, ManagerEmail.

From the Import table the records (excepting ManagerEmail) are then inserted into the Users table. Only once this has been done will the user now have a UserId. The challenge is now to update the newly created User record with the ManagerId (Which would be the Manangers UserId).

I could create a UserId and ManagerId field in the Import table and run a script to update these values after the User records have been created and then use this to update the Users table, however it would be a challenge to update the Users table based only on having the Email and ManagerEmail relationship in the Import table.

Please let me know if my explanation needs further clarification. Any help would be appreciated and I will continue researching in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out a solution using a CTE.

WITH
  cteImport (ManagerId, Email)
  AS
  (
    SELECT u.UserId, i.Email
    FROM Users u 
    INNER JOIN Import i 
    ON i.ManagerEmail = u.Email
  )
UPDATE Users
SET ManagerId = i.ManagerId
FROM cteImport i 
WHERE Users.Email = i.Email

Hope this can help someone else.